# Configuring Camel Routing for Grails 3.0.4

Tags: grails, routes, apache-camel

I am using grails 3.0.4 and install-plugin doesn't work anymore. I have added routing plugin in gradle dependencies but I can use the command grails create-route as in the online examples. I have created my own route class in grails-app/routes but when I run grails doesn't seem to use the route at all. Is there extra config that I have to do like create a bean somewhere?

my class is as follows:

```
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder

class TrackingMessageRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    def grailsApplication

    @Override
    void configure() {
        def config = grailsApplication?.config
        from('seda:input.queue').to('stream:out')
             from('mina2:tcp://localhost:553').to('stream:out')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The routing plugin has not yet been updated for Grails 3.
See https://github.com/grails/grails-core/wiki/Grails-3-Priority-Upgrade-Plugins for the Grails 3 readiness status of several important plugins.

Since Grails 3 is closely tied to Spring boot, it should be relatively easy to use Camel libraries directly (without need for a plugin). See http://camel.apache.org/spring-boot.html for potentially helpful info.

Answer (score 2):

Its true that the routing plugin has not been updated for grails 3 but like @jstell suggested, using camel libraries is actually easy. This is how I implemented my solution:

1. In build.gradle under dependencies add the following dependencies depending on the components you want to use as follows.

   runtime "org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.15.3"
           runtime "org.apache.camel:camel-groovy:2.15.3"
           runtime "org.apache.camel:camel-stream:2.15.3"
           //runtime "org.apache.camel:camel-netty:2.15.3"
           runtime "org.apache.camel:camel-netty4:2.15.3"
           runtime "org.apache.camel:camel-spring:2.15.3"
           runtime "org.apache.camel:camel-jms:2.15.3"
           runtime "org.apache.activemq:activemq-camel:5.11.1"
           runtime "org.apache.activemq:activemq-pool:5.11.1"
2. Create a route that extends RouteBuilder as follows:

   ```
   class TrackingMessageRoute extends RouteBuilder {
       def grailsApplication

       @Override
       void configure() {
           def config = grailsApplication?.config
           //from('netty4:tcp://192.168.254.3:553?sync=true&decoders=#decoders&encoder=#encoder').to('activemq:queue:Mimacs.Tracking.Queue')
           from('netty4:tcp://192.168.254.3:553?serverInitializerFactory=#sif&keepAlive=true&sync=true&allowDefaultCodec=false').to('activemq:queue:Mimacs.Tracking.Queue')
           from('activemq:queue:Mimacs.Tracking.Queue').bean(MimacsMessageListener.class)
       }
   }
   ```

   3. Configure a Camel Context in BootStrap.groovy. You can use SpringBeans in resources.groovy if you want

CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext(registry)
camelContext.addComponent("activemq",ActiveMQComponent.activeMQComponent("failover:tcp://localhost:61616"))
camelContext.addRoutes new TrackingMessageRoute()
camelContext.start()

NB. I left out certains part of code that do not affect this answer. If you have these then you ar good to go.